# PHP How to print barcode in 2 columns zebra prn code

Tags: php

I am stuck in coding, unable to get solution. I have PHP code which print barcode in zebraGC420T printer using prn code. I have attached prn file too. Everything is working fine, but getting double print for each print given.

For example, if I have to print 2 labels, it will print 4 lables and if I need to print 4 labels it will 16 labels. I know some where I have to add logic, so I need your suggestions to complete the code, please help me.

```
foreach ($barcodes as $item) {
    for ($r = 1; $r <= $item['quantity']; $r++) {

        $p = $item['quantity'];
        echo $p;

        //Label First///                                        
        $label .= "N\n";
        $label .= "A580,175,2,2,2,2,N,"."'.$item[site].'\n";
        $label .= "B586,68,2,1,2,6,40,B,"."'.$item[name].'\n";
        $label .= "A590,137,2,4,1,1,N,"."'.$item[name].'\n";                                        
        $label .= "A599,102,2,4,1,1,N,"."MRP\n";
        $label .= "A550,113,2,3,2,2,N,"."'.$item[price].'\n";

        //Label Second///
        $label .= "A275,175,2,2,2,2,N,"."'.$item[site].'\n";
        $label .= "B281,68,2,1,2,6,40,B,"."'.$item[name].'\n";
        $label .= "A285,137,2,4,1,1,N,"."'.$item[name].'\n";
        $label .= "A294,102,2,4,1,1,N,"."MRP\n";
        $label .= "A245,113,2,3,2,2,N,"."'.$item[price].'\n";
        $label .= "P1\n";
        $label .= '\n';
    }
$r++
```

Sample Barcode Design - https://www.dhresource.com/webp/m/0x0s/f2-albu-g3-M00-E4-05-rBVaHFYzWP-ABP9XAACXAOlRpWk369.jpg/glossy-white-pet-label-sticker-35mm-x-8mm.jpg

This is how I print to file and send it to barcode printer using dos command, every thing is fine, just not printing correct nos..

```
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$label  = "Q203,024\n";
$label .= "q831\n";
$label .= "rN\n";
$label .= "S5\n";
$label .= "D10\n";
$label .= "ZT\n";
$label .= "JF\n";
$label .= "O\n";
$label .= "R109,0\n";
$label .= "f100\n";
$label .= "N\n";
$label .= "A580,175,2,2,2,2,N,"."'POSSHINE'\n";
$label .= "B586,68,2,1,2,6,40,B,"."'1234567'\n";
$label .= "A590,137,2,4,1,1,N,"."'Lee Jeans'\n";
$label .= "A599,102,2,4,1,1,N,"."MRP\n";
$label .= "A550,113,2,3,2,2,N,"."'Rs.899'\n";
$label .= "A275,175,2,2,2,2,N,"."'Posshine'\n";
$label .= "B281,68,2,1,2,6,40,B,"."'1234567'\n";
$label .= "A285,137,2,4,1,1,N,"."'Lee Jeans'\n";
$label .= "A294,102,2,4,1,1,N,"."MRP\n";
$label .= "A245,113,2,3,2,2,N,"."'Rs.899'\n";
$label .= "P1\n";
$label .= '\n';
$current = $label;
file_put_contents($file, $current."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: This is how i print to file and send it to barcode printer using dos command, every thing is fine, just not printing correct nos..

Comment: You might want to include a bit more code as in your example you have two opening `{` and only one `}`

Comment: hi, i have closed both {}, while copying i might missed out., so can you provide me the solution for this problem how to print barcodes in 2 columns without wasting extra lables, i mean if i print 2 labels should print 2 only not 4 labels,